# FORM INPUT VALIDATION IN YII2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to validate form input in yii2, I want to check user's input against a certain value from the database.
In my model i have this

```
use backend\models\RealAccount;
class Amount extends Model
{
public $amount;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['amount'], 'number'],
        ['amount', 'checkBalance'],
        ['amount', 'compare', 'compareValue' => function($model) {
            return RealAccount::getAccountBalance();
            }, 'operator' => '<=', 'message' => \Yii::t('app','Insufficient balance')
        ],
    ];
}


public function checkBalance($attribute)
{
    /*check wallet balance is greater or equal to amount*/
    $balance =  RealAccount::getAccountBalance();
    if(!$balance >= $this->amount){
      $this->addError($attribute, \Yii::t('app','Insufficient balance');
    }

}
}
```

I tried both checkBlance, and also try compareValue but non of this work as I expected. NOTE i didn't use bot the same time, tired one it failed then i try the other,
Suppose my Balance is 200, if user input 201, i want to return error message. thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure that `$balance` return what do you expect? Did you turn on your ajax validation? You can use just `if($balance < $this->amount){`

Comment: Don't you mean `!($balance >= $this->amount)` or rather `$balance < $this->amount`? With `!$balance` you are negating `$balance` only.

Comment: @ Bizley @ vvpanchev I changed it as suggested by you guys and also ajax validation is on because i got error when i try to submit the form leaving the input field empty, but unfortunately it's not seem validating the amount and i'm supposed it should work